# CMake Unable to find Boost Libraries (System, Thread, Filesystem)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to install and use [DeepLab](https://bitbucket.org/aquariusjay/deeplab-public-ver2) for a segmentation project, but when trying to configure this using CMake it is unable to find boost libraries, despite identifying boost's version and location. I've tried following advice in similar questions by manually specifying locations but still encounter the same issue. Error messages attached below. Any idea what could be causing this issue?
Thanks in advance.

```
CMake Error at E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1956 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.0

  Boost include path: C:/local/boost_1_65_0

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_thread
          boost_filesystem

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (include)


Found gflags  (include: C:/Program Files/gflags/include, library: optimized;C:/Program Files/gflags/lib;debug;C:/Program Files/gflags/lib)
Found glog    (include: C:/Program Files/glog/include, library: optimized;C:/Program Files/glog/lib;debug;C:/Program Files/glog/lib)
CMake Error at E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:425 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "C:/Users/Benn/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py27_1.1.0/libraries/include/google/protobuf/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h"
  cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:4 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (include)


CMake Error at E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:431 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " / 1000000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_DIVIDE, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER
  (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:4 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (include)


CMake Error at E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:432 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " / 1000 % 1000": syntax error,
  unexpected exp_DIVIDE, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or
  exp_NUMBER (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:4 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (include)


CMake Error at E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:433 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " % 1000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_MOD, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER
  (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:4 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (include)


Found PROTOBUF Compiler: C:/Users/Benn/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py27_1.1.0/libraries/include/google/protobuf
CMake Error at cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:19 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCH needs at least 5 arguments total to
  command.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (include)


CMake Error at E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS
  HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES HL) (found version "")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindHDF5.cmake:905 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:27 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Without a CMakeLists.txt it is difficult to judge if this is a duplicate or not...

Comment: @André Hi Andre, the CMakeLists.txt can be seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/aquariusjay/deeplab-public-ver2/src/071ef5a59aad8d9e6e1f5b8dff3d7a5c984a3d3a/CMakeLists.txt?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Run `cmake`  with option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` - this will give you precise library filenames which are searched (and not found). Then check, that you have exactly these files in your Boost installation.

Comment: Did you build Boost yourself and installed it or did you used the binaries from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.65.0/ for installation? Is the installed version of the compiled Boost libraries/DLLs compatible with your compiler? Otherwise CMake cannot find them.